# Handle ARGV in Ruby without if...else block

Tags: ruby, oop

In a blog post about [unconditional programming](http://michaelfeathers.typepad.com/michael_feathers_blog/2013/11/unconditional-programming.html) Michael Feathers shows how limiting `if` statements can be used as a tool for reducing code complexity.

He uses a specific example to illustrate his point. Now, I've been thinking about other specific examples that could help me learn more about unconditional/`if`less/`for`less programming.

For example in this [cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)) clone there is an `if..else` block:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

if ARGV.length > 0
  ARGV.each do |f|
    puts File.read(f)
  end
else
  puts STDIN.read
end
```

It turns out ruby has `ARGF` which makes this program much simpler:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts ARGF.read
```

I'm wondering if `ARGF` didn't exist how could the above example be refactored so there is no `if..else` block?

Also interested in links to other illustrative specific examples.

Comment: I think you've misread that blog post as an absolute rule rather than as a tool in your toolbox. But in your case you could simplify your code by first creating an array of IO objects from `ARGV`, and use `STDIN` if that list is empty. `io = ARGV.map { |f| File.new(f) }; io = [STDIN] if !io.length;` Then your code can do what it likes with `io`. While this has strictly the same number of conditionals, it eliminates the if/else block and thus a branch: the code is linear. Since it separates gathering data from using it, you can put it in a method and reuse it further reducing complexity.

Comment: Cloning of cats is off-topic on Stack Overflow, please migrate to http://biology.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: @Schwern you are richt about the use, surely if it makes your code more difficult to readand probably slower but in your suggestion you still use an if

Comment: @peter Don't get hung up on the `if`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't always get rid of a conditional (maybe with an insane number of classes) and Michael Feathers isn't advocating that. Instead it's sort of a backlash against overuse of conditionals. We've all seen nightmare code that's endless chains of nested if/elsif/else and so has he.

> Moreover, people do routinely nest conditionals inside of conditionals.  Some of the worst code I've ever seen is a cavernous nightmare of nested conditions with odd bits of work interspersed within them. I suppose that the real problem with control structures is that they are often mixed with the work. I'm sure there's some way that we can see this as a form of single responsibility violation.

Rather than slavishly try to eliminate the condition, you could simplify your code by first creating an array of IO objects from ARGV, and use STDIN if that list is empty.

```
io = ARGV.map { |f| File.new(f) };
io = [STDIN] if !io.length;
```

Then your code can do what it likes with `io`.

While this has strictly the same number of conditionals, it eliminates the if/else block and thus a branch: the code is linear. More importantly, since it separates gathering data from using it, you can put it in a function and reuse it further reducing complexity. Once it's in a function, we can take advantage of early return.

```
# I don't have a really good name for this, but it's a
# common enough idiom. Perl provides the same feature as <>
def arg_files
    return ARGV.map { |f| File.new(f) } if ARGV.length;
    return [STDIN];
end
```

Now that it's in a function, your code to cat all the files or stdin becomes very simple.

```
arg_files.each { |f| puts f.read }
```

Comment: you still use an if, it is not what the OP asked, also using a method is not the OO way

Comment: @peter In programming, the customer isn't always right. I explained why Unconditional Programming is more of an exercise, a tool, at the top of the answer. As for OO, it would serve well as a method on a hypothetical `ARGV` class, but there is no such class, `ARGV` is an `Array`. Putting it on `Array` would be inappropriate; it does not apply for all arrays, just command line arguments. You pick and choose the tool for the job; as evidenced by the other answers that make things WAY more complex in the pursuit of eliminating the condition which ignores the purpose of the article.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can,

```
inputs = { ARGV => ARGV.map { |f| File.open(f) }, [] => [STDIN] }[ARGV]
inputs.map(&:read).map(&method(:puts))
```

Though that's [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) and too clever for its own good.

Still, how does it work?

- It uses a hash to store two alternatives.
- Map `ARGV` to an array of open files
- Map `[]` to an array with `STDIN`, effectively overwriting the `ARGV` entry if it is empty
- Access `ARGV` in the hash, which returns `[STDIN]` if it is empty
- Read all open inputs and print them

Don't write that code though.

As mentioned in [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41335425), unconditional programming is not about avoiding `if` expressions at all costs but about striving for readable and intention revealing code. And sometimes that just means using an `if` expression.

Answer (score -2):

First, although the principle is good, you have to consider other things that are more importants such as readability and perhaps speed of execution.

That said, you could monkeypatch the String class to add a read method and put STDIN and the arguments in an array and start reading from the beginning until the end of the array minus 1, so stopping before STDIN if there are arguments and go on until -1 (the end) if there are no arguments.

```
class String
  def read
    File.read self if File.exist? self
  end
end

puts [*ARGV, STDIN][0..ARGV.length-1].map{|a| a.read}
```

Before someone notices that I still use an if to check if a File exists, you should have used two if's in your example to check this also and if you don't, use a rescue to properly inform the user.

EDIT: if you would use the patch, read about the possible problems at these links
http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/04/alternatives-for-redefining-methods.html
http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-ways-to-monkey-patch-without-making-a-mess/

Since the read method isn't part of String the solutions using alias and super are not necessary, if you plan to use a Module, here is how to do that

```
module ReadString
  def read
    File.read self if File.exist? self
  end
end

class String
  include ReadString
end
```

EDIT: just read about a safe way to monkey patch, for your documentation see https://solidfoundationwebdev.com/blog/posts/writing-clean-monkey-patches-fixing-kaminari-1-0-0-argumenterror-comparison-of-fixnum-with-string-failed?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email

Comment: -1 for suggesting a monkey patch to `String`. It works fine as a function. Also `File.exist?` is not sufficient, a file can exist and not be readable. It also introduces a race condition, a file can exist and then be deleted before you open it. The best way to check if you can open a file is to try and open the file and deal with the exception if it fails.

Comment: @Schwern, have you read my reservations ? it's not because he shouldn't use it that he shouldn't know of the possibility along with the associated problems. Monkey patching is generally used in Ruby and yes you need to know what you do, to make sure he knows that I added a few links