# Handle command-line switch in Ruby without if...else block

Tags: ruby, oop, if-statement

In a blog post about [unconditional programming](http://michaelfeathers.typepad.com/michael_feathers_blog/2013/11/unconditional-programming.html) Michael Feathers shows how limiting `if` statements can be used as a tool for reducing code complexity.

He uses a specific example to illustrate his point. Now, I've been thinking about other specific examples that could help me learn more about unconditional/`if`less/`for`less programming.

For example, using [OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) I made a [cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)) clone that will upcase the stream if the `--upcase` switch is set:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'optparse'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: cat [options] [file ...]"

  opts.on("-u", "--upcase", "Upcase stream") do
    options[:upcase] = true
  end
end.parse!

if options[:upcase]
  puts ARGF.read.upcase
else
  puts ARGF.read
end
```

How would I handle that switch without an `if..else` block?

Also interested in links to other illustrative specific examples.

Comment: Why do you assume there is a way to make this particular decision without using "if", or that it's even desirable to do so, based on a single one-page blog post?

Comment: Because the else clause is the same as the if clause but just adds a step, you can remove the repetition and make your code linear by unconditionally doing the common bit, and then conditionally doing the extra stuff. `data = ARGF.read; data.upcase! if options[:upcase]`

Comment: @meagar Would you mind reopening these? They have pretty clear answers.

Comment: @Schwern Post-fix `if` is still an `if`. Moving the `if` to the end of the line isn't making your code "unconditional".

Comment: @meagar It is making it simpler by removing a branch and linearizing it. Would you reopen the question please so we can offer options and clarify what the blog post trying to teach? [Michael Feathers knows what he's talking about](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=dp_byline_sr_book_1?ie=UTF8&text=Michael+Feathers&search-alias=books&field-author=Michael+Feathers&sort=relevancerank).

Comment: @Schwern My point is that it doesn't remove a branch. Postfix `if` is still an `if`, the branch is still there in the same place it was before. The fact that we're sitting here debating it is a good indication that this question is off-topic.

Comment: @meagar This question isn't deserving of an admin hammer. It has very clear code and a very clear question about it. Clarifying confusion about software engineering techniques is on topic, providing better versions of code is also on topic, discussing those changes is also on topic, we do it all the time. muistooshort also provided a simplification and clarification. Reopen the question and see what happens. If it goes off the rails, you can always close it.

Comment: @meagar: Smalltalk doesn't even have conditionals. It also doesn't have loops. Yet, you can still make decisions in Smalltalk programs. In fact, the Smalltalk standard library contains implementations of loops and conditionals *as library methods* without any language support. This is existence proof of the fact that *any* conditional code can be written using pure object-oriented message dispatch. This is also demonstrated in λ-calculus, which also doesn't have conditionals or loops, but the implementation is actually trivial (and in fact, the object-oriented encoding of conditionals is …

Comment: … exactly isomorphic to the Church Encoding of Booleans in the λ-calculus). That is the basis of the Replace Conditional With Polymorphism Refactoring, which also is the answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'optparse'

options = { :transform => :itself }
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: cat [options] [file ...]"
  opts.on("-u", "--upcase", "Upcase stream") do
    options[:transform] = :upcase
  end
  # add more options for downcase, reverse, etc ...
end.parse!

puts ARGF.read.send(options[:transform])
```

This worked quite well, I am actually surprised how well that worked.

What has been changed?

- The option is internally renamed to `:transform`
- The internal default value is `:itself`
- The command line switch sets the internal option to `:upcase`
- Call the method with `send`

Not all `if` statements can be improved upon like this though. I would guess the idea of unconditional programming is to prefer a combination of meaningful default values, as I did above, and intention revealing functions whenever it seems reasonable but not at all costs.

Here are some examples of intention revealing functions,

- `max`
- `min`
- `Hash#fetch`
- `Enumerable#detect`
- `Enumerable#select`
- `Enumerable#chunk`
- `Enumerable#drop_while`
- `Enumerable#slice_when`
- `Enumerable#take_while`
- etc...

Another related practice is `for`less programming.

If you want to practice unconditional and `for`less programming best look for examples that process arrays and strings and make use of the many "functional" methods in Ruby's enumerable module.

Here is an example of string justification without `for` and `if`,

```
str = 'This is an example to be aligned to both margins'    
words = str.split
width, remainder = (50 - words.map(&:length).inject(:+)).divmod(words.length - 1)
words.take(words.length - 1).each { |each| width.times { each << 32 }}
words.take(words.length - 1).shuffle.take(remainder).each { |each| each << 32 }
p words.join
# => "This  is an example to  be aligned to both margins"
```

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "There is an example to make Justify the text us"? It seems like you are inserting spaces in the string, but I'm not sure what you're justifying to. The left, center, or right?

Comment: Justifying means aligning to both margins, the others would be called flushing left/right or centering.

Answer (score 1):

Eliminating conditions is a tool for reducing complexity, not an end goal. [I explained that better in my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41337657/14660). In this case the condition must be there because whether or not `options[:upcase]` is set is part of the logic. But you can at least eliminate the duplication.

Because the else clause is the same as the if clause but just adds a step, you can remove the repetition and make your code linear by unconditionally doing the common bit, and then conditionally doing the extra stuff.

```
data = ARGF.read;
data.upcase! if options[:upcase];
```